# sizeof, offsetof, and alignment via TemplateHaskell

Tags: haskell, template-haskell, hsc2hs

I wonder if someone has implemented analogues of `hsc2hs` pragmas via `TemplateHaskell`? It feels like it should be doable, since TH runs on target platform at compile time, and GHC always has a C compiler lying around. This could be useful as another way of generating haskell wrappers for C structs and deriving stuff for them.

The question is: if there is such a library, point me please. Otherwise, tell me if I miss something and this is impossible or does not make sense.